# How to return the given input values not available in array using mongodb query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am having one input arrays,EX: `let UPID = ["0","1","10"]`. i have to check `members.regularStudent` whether given input values available or not ?, suppose not available means i have to push one array and return the results

> My documents:

```
{
    "_id" : "5bb20d7556db6915846da67f",
    "members" : {
        "regularStudent" : [
            "3",
            "4"
        ]
    }
},

{
    "_id" : "5bb20d7556db6915846da55f",
    "members" : {
        "regularStudent" : [
            "1",
            "2"
        ]
    }
}
```

> My Expected Output

```
    [
        "0",
        "10"
    ]
```

> My Code:

```
    let UPID = ["0","1","10"]
db.Groups.find(
    /*{
    "members.regularStudent": { $nin: UPIDs }
    }*/
)
.forEach(function(objects){
    print(objects)
})
```

> I had updated `mycode`, kindly see top on my question section, `print(objects)` means i am having the my objects, based on this variable can you update your answer,

** print(objects) **

```
{
    "_id" : "5bb20d7556db6915846da67f",
    "members" : {
        "regularStudent" : [
            "3",
            "4"
        ]
    }
},

{
    "_id" : "5bb20d7556db6915846da55f",
    "members" : {
        "regularStudent" : [
            "1",
            "2"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map` method in *combination* with `filter`.

```js
let UPID = ["0","1","10"]; 
let docs = [{ "_id" : "5bb20d7556db6915846da67f", "members" : { "regularStudent" : [ "3", "4" ] } },
{ "_id" : "5bb20d7556db6915846da55f", "members" : { "regularStudent" : [ "1", "2" ] } }]

let ids = [].concat(...docs.map(elem => elem.members.regularStudent));
console.log(UPID.filter(id => !ids.includes(id)));
```

Comment: Can you please update my code ? , because you given JS but i need mongodb query

Comment: I had updated `mycode`, kindly see top on my question section, print(objects) means i am having the my objects, based on this variable can you update your answer,

Answer (score 0):

Here I use forEach to iterate through the data to get all of the regularStudent data into one array then use filter to filter out the data from UPID array.

```js
const UPID = ["0", "1" , "10"]
let data = [
  {
      "_id" : "5bb20d7556db6915846da67f",
      "members" : {
          "regularStudent" : [
              "3",
              "4"
          ]
      }
  },
  {
      "_id" : "5bb20d7556db6915846da55f",
      "members" : {
          "regularStudent" : [
              "1",
              "2"
          ]
      }
  }
]
let resularStudents = []
data.forEach(d => {
  d.members.regularStudent.forEach(rs => {
    resularStudents.push(rs)
  })
})
var result = UPID.filter(
    function(d) {
      return this.indexOf(d) < 0;
    },
    resularStudents
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can you please update my code ? , because you given JS but i need mongodb query

Comment: I had updated `mycode`, kindly see top on my question section, print(objects) means i am having the my objects, based on this variable can you update your answer,